# Difference between Transformation matrix and simple coordinate transformations

Tags: linear-algebra

I would like to figure out the difference between two things: transformation matrix and coordinate transformations between the Cartesian system and spherical coordinate system.
It is absolutely clear how to transform Cartesian system to Shperical, simply by:
\begin{align}
x &= r \sin \theta \cos \varphi \\
y &= r \sin \theta \sin \varphi \\
z &= r \cos \theta
\end{align}
but the thing that is not clear to me - how to transform $(x,y,z)$ to $(\theta, \lambda, r)$ using the matrix?
I assume that it should be something like this: $\mathbf{a} = (x,y,z)$, $\mathbf{b} = (\theta, \lambda, r)$, where $\mathbf{a}$ and $\bf{b}$ are column vectors and there is some matrix $M$ such that $\mathbf{a} = M \mathbf{b}$.
Then I found in the web such matrix, the view is:
$$M = \begin{pmatrix} \sin\theta \cos\lambda & \cos\theta \cos\theta & -\sin\lambda \\ \sin\theta \sin\lambda & \cos\theta \sin\lambda & \cos\lambda \\ \cos\theta &-\sin\theta & 0 \end{pmatrix},$$

but when I start multiplying I do not get the equations on the first image$\ldots$
So how does transformation matrix look and what am I confusing?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It is rather difficult to follow your post: not ony one has  to open the images, but also different symbols are used for the angles...

Comment: If you have extracted your formulas from different sources, then most probably they use a different convention. May be the matrix $M$ is not the transformation itself, but the **Jacobian**: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_common_coordinate_transformations#From_spherical_coordinates

Comment: Yes, sorry for different sumbols: lambda <--> phi, others are the same..
So then, can you tell me please, how does transformation matrix look in this case (Cartesian -> Sperical c.) and how to find it?

Comment: You could have googled "cartesian spherical matrix" more easily than writing the question, http://www.web-formulas.com/Math_Formulas/Linear_Algebra_Transform_from_Cartesian_to_Spherical_Coordinate.aspx

Comment: When I google it I am getting something like this: http://www.web-formulas.com/Math_Formulas/Linear_Algebra_Transform_from_Cartesian_to_Spherical_Coordinate.aspx, which returns me to the question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spherical coordinates are given by:

\begin{align}
x &= r\sin\vartheta\cos\phi \\
y &= r\sin\vartheta\sin\phi \\
z &= r\cos\vartheta.
\end{align}

We can write this as a transformation mapping $\Phi$:
$$\Phi(r,\vartheta,\phi) = \begin{pmatrix} \sin\vartheta\cos\phi \\
r\sin\vartheta\sin\phi \\
r\cos\vartheta \end{pmatrix}=: \begin{pmatrix} x\\ y \\ z \end{pmatrix}$$

This transformation $\Phi$ is *not* linear, hence it cannot be expressed as linear mapping / matrix multiplication.

The matrix you stated above is the Jacobian defined as follows (modulo mistakes):
$$ J = \frac{\partial\Phi}{\partial(r,\vartheta,\phi)} = \begin{pmatrix} \sin\vartheta\cos\phi & r\cos\vartheta\cos\phi 
 & -r\sin\vartheta\sin\phi \\ \sin\vartheta\sin\phi & r\cos\vartheta\sin\phi & r\sin\vartheta\cos\phi \\ \cos\vartheta & -r\sin\vartheta &0
\end{pmatrix}$$

So for example it is:
\begin{align}
J_{1,1} = \frac{\partial\Phi_1}{\partial r} &= \frac \partial {∂r} r\sin\vartheta\cos\phi = \sin\vartheta\cos\phi, \\
J_{1,2} = \frac{\partial\Phi_1}{\partial\vartheta} &= \frac \partial {\partial\vartheta} r\sin\vartheta\cos\phi = r\cos\vartheta\cos\phi.
\end{align}

Using this Jacobian it is possible to write the conversion of differentials as matrix-multiplication.
$$\begin{pmatrix} \Bbb dx \\ \Bbb dy \\ \Bbb dz \end{pmatrix} = J\begin{pmatrix} \Bbb dr \\ \Bbb d\vartheta \\ \Bbb d\varphi \end{pmatrix}.$$
It is important to keep in mind, that this conversion is only valid for differentials.

Now, why do we need that matrix at all?

Given the transformation $\Phi(u_1, \ldots, u_n) = (v_1, \ldots, v_n)$ and given several conditions, it holds
$${\int_{\Phi(M)} f(v) \, \Bbb dv} = {\int_Mf(\Phi(u)) \, {|\det\Phi'(u)|} \,\Bbb du.}$$
This is the *substitution rule* in $n$ dimensions.

If we apply this theorem to the spherical coordinates, we get:
$${\int_{\Phi(M)} f(x,y,z) \, \Bbb dx \, \Bbb dy \, \Bbb dz} = {\int_Mf(r\sin\vartheta\cos\phi, r\sin\vartheta\sin\phi, r\cos\vartheta) [r^2\sin\vartheta]  \, \Bbb dr \, \Bbb d\vartheta \, \Bbb d\phi.}$$

You can find more information about the Jacobian matrix [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant).